# Yii - Cloudcontrol - Git

Tags: git

When i using cloudcontrol to create app im getting this repeating answer, cant create app name 
I have used thru Git Repository

> $ cctrlapp ayiitest3 create php 
>    "Git seems to be installed! Using "Git as repository type. name: App with this Name already exists.

So i have used different app name, also i got these same answer like

> $ cctrlapp abcd create php 
>   Git seems to be installed! Using "Git" as repository type.
>   name: App with this Name already exists.

I tried directly in cloudcontrol site there i got this error

> Failed to add app ayiitest. A app with this name already exists

Can anyone help???

Answer (score 0):

this is not a genereal error. I checked and all the three app names you used already exist: ayiitest3  ayiitest abcd. Especially everything with "ayiitest" seems to very popular.

Could you try using another name?